# Laravel 6 : Foreign key not saving

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new in laravel, trying to save an entity with foreign key.

I have a table called **invoices**, ***invoices has foreign key client_id***.

I created a create.blade like below

```
<form action="{{route('invoice.store')}}" method="post">

@csrf

@method('post')

<input type="text" name="client_id" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control">
<button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>

</form>
```

In store method I have tried like below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        Invoice::create($request->all());
}
```

In model I have given all fields in fillable

```
protected $fillable = ['client_id ','mobile','invoice_date'];
```

Problem is while I am going to save data, I am getting below error

[image]

After using dd, getting below response

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "ftg05U1OoQsmqrRA16D8FT0jbjqkgJBaaUuAkhUS"
  "_method" => "post"
  "client_id" => "1"
  "mobile" => "01813268086"
]
```

My question is why client_id not in insert field and why it's not saving ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra space on `client_id`

**This**

```php
protected $fillable = ['client_id ','mobile','invoice_date'];
```

**Should be**

```php
protected $fillable = ['client_id','mobile','invoice_date'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely it will not save cause there's a token and method on the response and it will find column named _token and _method. To solve this you can change it to.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Invoice::create($request->except('_token', '_method'));
}
```

or to be more sure of

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Invoice::create([
             'client_id ' => $request->client_id,
             'mobile' => $request->mobile,
             'invoice_date' => date('Y-m-d')
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know without client_id, there has no problem with save ? _token and _method not an issues if I saved using request->all().

Comment: Did you try the second solution of mine ?

Comment: I known about this solution before your ans, but problem is if I have 30 fields I have to write all fields manually like you did. It's a solution not an appropriate solution.I think you got my point. Sorry for that.

Comment: I don't know why it's not inserting when you put client_id, base on the error, your client id is empty and cant insert new record because client id is required. double check the data type in your table and cast the client id to int since client id is surely an integer

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try to get client_id. Is it coming

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        dd($request->client_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $data = $request->except(['_token','_method']);
        Invoice::insert($data);
}
```